# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" with my IntPtr into my struct - C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamworks-api

I'm working on my multiplayer game (with FacepunchStudio implementation) on Unity, and I have a weird behaviour with my unmarshalling.

For send data between players, I use the 'SteamSocketManager' and I need to use Marshal. So, I have created 2 struct:

```cs
public struct Data
{
    public TypeInfo typeData;
    public IntPtr data;
}

public struct PlayerInfo
{
    public uint idNetwork;
    public CommandType typeCommand;
    public Vector3 position, rotation;
    public float xAnimator, yAnimator;
}
```

PlayerInfo: it's for all player information.

Data: it's to make a generic structure for all data between the server and clients.

When a player is connected to the socket, the server sends a request for creating the player locally and create a 'remote' of the player to the other players.

```cs
public override void OnConnected(Connection connection, ConnectionInfo data)
    {
        base.OnConnected(connection, data);
        Debug.Log($"{data.Identity} has joined the game");
        
        // Prepare the player experience
        uint idUser = connection.Id;
        Vector3 playerPosition = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-area, area), 1, UnityEngine.Random.Range(area, area));
        Debug.Log($"new pos: {playerPosition}");

        // @ 1 > Create a new PlayerInfo for the server
        PlayerInfo infoPlayer = new PlayerInfo()
        {
            idNetwork = idUser,
            typeCommand = CommandType.Remote,
            position = playerPosition,
            rotation = new Vector3(0,0,0),
            xAnimator = 0,
            yAnimator = 0
        };
        players.Add(idUser, infoPlayer);
        int sizePlayerInformation = Marshal.SizeOf(infoPlayer);

        // @ 2 > Send the 'Remote' PlayerInfo to the other players
        int sizeMarcel = Marshal.SizeOf(infoPlayer);
        IntPtr infoRemotePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeMarcel);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(infoPlayer, infoRemotePtr, false);
        Data remoteD = new Data
        {
            typeData = TypeInfo.PlayerInfo,
            data = infoRemotePtr
        };
        IntPtr dataRemote = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(remoteD));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(remoteD, dataRemote, false);
        SteamManager.Instance.RelaySocketMessageReceived(dataRemote, Marshal.SizeOf(remoteD), idUser);

        // @ 3 > Send the 'Create' Player to the new player
        infoPlayer.typeCommand = CommandType.Create;
        int sizeCreatePlayerData = Marshal.SizeOf(infoPlayer);
        IntPtr infoCompressed = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeCreatePlayerData);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(infoPlayer, infoCompressed, false);
        Data dataInfoPlayer = new Data
        {
            typeData = TypeInfo.PlayerInfo,
            data = infoCompressed
        };
        IntPtr dataCreate = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(dataInfoPlayer));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(dataInfoPlayer, dataCreate, false);
        Result sc = connection.SendMessage(dataCreate, Marshal.SizeOf(dataInfoPlayer), SendType.Reliable);
        if (sc != Result.OK)
        {
            Result retry = connection.SendMessage(dataCreate, Marshal.SizeOf(dataInfoPlayer), SendType.Reliable);
            if (retry != Result.OK) Debug.LogError("EET BRO, CA MARCHE PAS KENNY");
        }
        Debug.Log(dataCreate);
    }
```

And when the player receives a new message from the server, this message is unmarshall by this
Method: `Data data = MultiPlayerSocket.UncompressData(messageIntPtr);`

After, I check if the type of the data is a 'PlayerInfo'.

If is true: a unmarshall this data into a PlayerInfo struct, and a execute all actions wanted.

```cs
public void ProcessMessageFromSocketServer(IntPtr messageIntPtr, int dataBlockSize)
    {
        try
        {
            // Data decompressing
            print($"<< DECOMPRESS +{messageIntPtr}");
            Data data = MultiPlayerSocket.UncompressData(messageIntPtr);
            print("data.data = " + data.data);

            // Do something with received message
            if (data.typeData == TypeInfo.PlayerInfo)
            {
                print("Execute Player Info");
                print(data.data + "|| " + data.typeData);
                PlayerInfo player = (PlayerInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(data.data, typeof(PlayerInfo));
                print($"DATA DECOMPRESSED (Player == )");
                print("Player: "+ player+ "|| idNet: "+player.idNetwork);
                ExecutePlayerDataCommand(player);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Unable to process message from socket server \n\n --[ERROR({e.Source})]-- \n\n "+e.Message);
        }
    }
```

All this system works if you are connected in 'Owner' of the Lobby. But if you are connected just in 'Client', a have this error:

```
Litelo invited you to his lobby.
Client joined the lobby
SocketIP_Local: 3938562153
wouhu, connection right here '$-$ 
<< DECOMPRESS +2249505835568
data.data = 2387748430064
Execute Player Info
2387748430064|| PlayerInfo
Unable to process message from socket server 

 --[ERROR()]-- 

 Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Connection Got A Message 2249505835568
```

the problem seems to from

```
PlayerInfo player = (PlayerInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(data.data, typeof(PlayerInfo));
```

Anybody can help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Sounds like your server is sending an address to data that is in the server's memory, and your client is trying to dereference that memory location. That definitely won't work because the same address on different hosts or processes is going to have different things living there.

Comment: Yeah, but how a can send the data from this IntPtr? I don't see how doing it in an other way.. maybe by copy the IntPtr into a byte [] into this structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work:

```
        IntPtr infoCompressed = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeCreatePlayerData);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(infoPlayer, infoCompressed, false);
        Data dataInfoPlayer = new Data
        {
            typeData = TypeInfo.PlayerInfo,
            data = infoCompressed
        };
```

This creates an unmanaged pointer to a data structure and then adds that pointer(!) to the transmission object. That pointer has no meaning on the other side. It's interesting you "only" get a NullReferenceException, as this could give you errors that are much worse. Side note: You're leaking the unmanaged memory.

Why don't you just use a standard serialization, using Json or XML? Your data structures aren't that complicated.

Comment: I can only transmit an IntPtr with the SteamSocket system. And yeah, I'm gonna try with JSON, I don't know  why a have not thinks to this alternative; thanks you

Comment: Nice !! it's work nicely now, thanks you !

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept the answer (checkmark to the left)